# Having two types of users in Laravel 5

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am wondering if there is a better way of handling how I have my authenticated users in regards of different types of users.

I have a basic user and an administrator user. The basic user obviously will only have access to basic pages and the administrator user needs to have access to other pages that the basic user cannot have access to.

What I have been doing is: I created a super_user column in my table and adding:

```
    if(Auth::user()->super_user == 0) {
        return Redirect::to('/')->with('error', 'You do not have permission to access this page');
    }
```

to each page that I do not want a basic user to be able to access. Now, this worked but I am starting to transition my apps to Laravel 5 and I am thinking there is a different way I can handle this.

Comment: @Lunx if you're happy with my answer below, accept it :)

Comment: Sorry about that mate! That actually worked and I was able to use your guidance to solve my issue!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best way to handle user roles in your case is to use [Middleware](http://laravel.com/docs/master/middleware).

1. Create middleware:

```
namespace App\Http\Middleware;

use Closure;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Guard;

class Admin
{
    /**
     * The Guard implementation.
     *
     * @var Guard
     */
    protected $auth;

    /**
     * Create a new filter instance.
     *
     * @param  Guard  $auth
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct(Guard $auth)
    {
        $this->auth = $auth;
    }

    /**
     * Handle an incoming request.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @param  \Closure  $next
     * @return mixed
     */
    public function handle($request, Closure $next)
    {
        if (!$this->auth->getUser()->super_user) {
            return redirect->to('/')
                ->with('error', 'You do not have permission to access this page');
            }
        }

        return $next($request);
    }
}
```

2. Add it to `app\Http\Kernel.php`:

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
    'admin' => 'App\Http\Middleware\Admin',
];
```

3. Use middleware in your routes:

```
Route::group(['middleware' => ['admin']], function() {
    // your route
});
```