# Laravel 5 - Role permissions

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I try to make my own permission system. but got a problem with the code when if the user doesn't have a specific role they can't access the page.

Here is my code:

```
public function compose($view)
{
    $roleid = Session::get('role_id');
    $userid = Session::get('user_id');
    $additional_role = Session::get('additional_role');

    $roles = explode(';', $additional_role);

    $segment = Request::segment('1');

    $joins = [];
    foreach ($roles as $role) 
    {
        $query = DB::table('roles')->where('id', $role)->first();
        $joins[] = $query->link;

    }


    foreach($joins as $join) {
        var_dump($join); var_dump($segment);

        if ($join == $segment) 
        {
              return redirect($segment);
        } 
        else
        {
            return redirect('/');
        }   
    }         



}
```

i make the code within a composer so i can keep booting it up. But i can't make it work, even the user doesn't have the role they not redirected to '/'.

Is there any way to make it work? So they won't get into the page and they will get into the page if they have the role.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Having two types of users in Laravel 5](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29040123/having-two-types-of-users-in-laravel-5)

Comment: @limonte hi. thanks for replying. nope. this apps only for backend so there is no front end user and i already change all the require table to staff. and all the login is perfectly fine. i've tried to vardump join and segment they all return like i want. the problem when i try to compare the result is not get into that.

Answer (score 0):

where do you have this logic?

i think in l5 best place to permissions and auth logic is "Http/Middleware", 
there you can add your file with handle method and logic within, and then you must edit  kernel.php

```
protected $routeMiddleware = [
        'auth'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\Authenticate',
        'auth.basic'    => 'Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\AuthenticateWithBasicAuth',
        'guest'         => 'App\Http\Middleware\RedirectIfAuthenticated',
        'test'          => 'App\Http\Middleware\yourFile',
    ];
```

you can view great solution for laravel acl here : https://gist.github.com/amochohan/8cb599ee5dc0af5f4246

and then you can easy make your role permissions